# Winamp and subtitles (automatic download)

Tags: automation, winamp, subtitles

Is there a tool/plug-in to automatically download subtitle for movies played with Winamp?

Comment: Just to clarify, thou'rt looking for something similar to VLSub for VLC, but for Winamp, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically, but [this story on torrentfreak](http://torrentfreak.com/tinysubs-real-time-subtitles-search-110302/) pointed me to tinysubs.com which will at least get you to the end result.

There are lots of sites out there that do a similar thing but be warned, [some question the legality!](http://torrentfreak.com/wikisubtitles-taken-down-by-spanish-anti-piracy-outfit-080520/)